# First IF statement is working good while the next ones are not anymore

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

The first IF statement is really working good and the other IF statements that follow do not work. When I click the button nothing happens.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your name?" Then
        Label1.Text = "Hi there kid! I will tell you later!"
        Return
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your age?" Then
            Label1.Text = "I was made in January 31,2014 well that is my birth date!"
            Return



            If TextBox1.Text = "Hi" Then
                Label1.Text = "Hi there also!"

            Else
                Label1.Text = "Do you have anything you want to say other than that?"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using "Return" exits out of your event handler

Comment: @Jesse when i removed Return it still acts the same.. :*(

Comment: Your ifs are also nested, it's impossible for TextBox1.Text.Trim to equal "What is your age?" if it's already equal to "What is your name?".

Comment: You need to add some detail on how you think it should work.

Comment: @Ken White No sir...that topic does not answer my question :)

Comment: @TheNewbie We really all want to help each other... But for the time being, you should really spend a little bit more time analyzing your code before you post a question. I'm not saying the question is annoying, NOT AT ALL, but to be a good programmer, you must allow yourself to think first before finally giving up if all else fails :) The time you spend thinking, regardless if you get the answer or not, will definitely improve your algorithm skills :)

Comment: It's the same question (My if statement isn't working), with almost the identical same code. I still think it's a duplicate. I also think you should learn to use the debugger, which would help you solve your problems like this yourself. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Ok forgive me because I am just a beginner programmer :) Thanks for your concern anyway :) It is identical in a way that it is my starting code and I added new codes which gave me a new dilemma.

Comment: You've posted two questions with almost identical code in less than an hour. Spend some time trying to figure things out yourself before posting here (as I said, start with the debugger - it's great when you're learning, because you can actually solve the problem and learn in the process).

Comment: @KenWhite Hi Sir, I've posted a question that nobody answered :( Here's the link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454519/difference-between-connectioninfo-class-and-crystal-reports-datasourceconnectio Can you please help me on this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can remove return and use else if for the other if. it should be fine

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your name?" Then
        Label1.Text = "Hi there kid! I will tell you later!"

    else if TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your age?" Then
        Label1.Text = "I was made in January 31,2014 well that is my birth date!"

    else if TextBox1.Text = "Hi" Then
        Label1.Text = "Hi there also!"

    Else
        Label1.Text = "Do you have anything you want to say other than that?"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks this code that you gave worked like a charm however i removed the 2 end ifs because it is not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your name?" Then
        Label1.Text = "Hi there kid! I will tell you later!"
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "What is your age?" Then
        Label1.Text = "I was made in January 31,2014 well that is my birth date!"
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "Hi" Then
        Label1.Text = "Hi there also!"
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Do you have anything you want to say other than that?"
    End If
End Sub
```

Try that

Comment: instead it shows the else statement instead of the if statement.